# subquery returning multiple rows..how to deal with it?

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT requestID
FROM request
WHERE userId = (
    SELECT userID
    FROM department
    WHERE desig = 'E'
    AND dept = (
        SELECT dept
        FROM department
        WHERE userId = it18
        AND desig = 'FM'
      )
);
```

Comment: Please we are people and we want details.

Comment: Apparently one of your subqueries returns more than one result.  If we knew what your tables looked like, then maybe we could help.  Also, have you thought about using `JOIN` instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be much clearer to write this query using [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
select distinct r.requestID 
from 
    request r
    join department d
        on d.userId = r.userID
        and desig = 'E'
    join department d2
        on d2.dept = d.dept
        and d2.desig = 'FM'
        and d2.userId = 'it18'
```

Alternately, You could simply replace the `=` with [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT requestID
FROM request
WHERE userId IN (
    SELECT userID
    FROM department
    WHERE desig = 'E'
    AND dept IN (
        SELECT dept
        FROM department
        WHERE userId = it18
        AND desig = 'FM'
      )
);
```

They should return identical results, but try both to see if there's any difference in performance.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways of dealing with it:

Option 1: Change to `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)`, like this:

```
SELECT requestID
FROM request
WHERE userId IN (
    SELECT userID
    FROM department
    WHERE desig = 'E'
    AND dept IN (
        SELECT dept
        FROM department
        WHERE userId = it18
        AND desig = 'FM'
      )
);
```

Option 2: Force only one result by using an aggregate function like `MAX()`, like this:

```
SELECT requestID
FROM request
WHERE userId = (
    SELECT MAX(userID)
    FROM department
    WHERE desig = 'E'
    AND dept = (
        SELECT MAX(dept)
        FROM department
        WHERE userId = it18
        AND desig = 'FM'
      )
);
```